# Mysql where like exact number?

Tags: mysql

I've multi select tree categories table

```
-- id | title  | parentids
-- 1  | black  | 22
-- 2  | white  | 1,3
-- 22 | red    | 1,2
```

Query :

```
SELECT * FORM table WHERE parentids LIKE '%2%'
```

**Return :** **black** and **red**

**My goal :** since parentids grouped array i need it to return only **red**

any idea is very much appreciated

Comment: It would be much, much easier if you would rearrange your database schema and put a m:n table children/parents.

Comment: It is very bad db design to store forgin keys as csv.

Comment: `SELECT * FORM table WHERE find_in_set(2,parentids) >0`

Comment: read about `find_in_set()`

Comment: @glglgl do u have example for your suggestion ?

Comment: It should be a table with 2 columns: child, parent. It should have the following entries for your example: (1, 22), (2, 1), (2, 3), (22, 1), (22, 2)

Comment: @glglgl how did i mess that ! :/ i am in the end of my project, should do this next time .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Correct way:**

Normalize your structure, because now it is combination of hierarchy and csv column.

*First Normal Form -> data in column is atomic*

Your sample data contains cycles (probably not intended):

[image]

You should aim for `Adjacency List Model` (if it should be hierarchy) something like:

```
╔════╦═══════╦═══════════╗
║ id ║ title ║ parentid  ║
╠════╬═══════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ xxx   ║ NULL      ║     -- root element
║  2 ║ yyy   ║ 1         ║
║  3 ║ zzz   ║ 2         ║
║  4 ║ uuu   ║ 2         ║
╚════╩═══════╩═══════════╝
```

**Workaround:**

```
SELECT * FORM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2',parentids) > 0
```

Comment: I've already upvoted your answer but OP probably needs an example of a good db structure

Comment: agreed with @DenysSéguret could u plz provide example structure :)

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers Please provide graph of your sample hierarchy, now it has cycle (1 -> 22 -> 1 ...)

Comment: @lad2025 table has id,title,parentids  , id <- is primary key ,  data inserted dynamically and infinite subcategories